# Making an edit without bumping the puzzle up?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, editing

I wanted to ask if there is a way to edit a puzzle/answer without bumping the topic up? I am asking because I am a bit of a perfectionist and like improving my questions occasionally if I see something better can be done. For example now I just noticed that I've been sloppy with the editing of the picture in my [Desperate Housewives in Brazil](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40293/desperate-housewives-in-brazil) puzzle. Can I change it to a better one without making the question active again?

P.S. Still have no idea how that one got 40 votes.

Comment: [Declined](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23241/) (with many duplicates) on meta.SE.